# Macro to compare two columns and insert one line if missing

Tags: vba, list, automation, compare

here is what I'm trying to achieve, in order to get rid of a lot of manual works. I basically have two lists, each made of two columns (we'll call it colA, colB, codD and colE). The first list (A+B) is normally bigger than the second (D+E), so my goal is to automate the process of spotting missing entries, insert a line when found one (actually, scroll down only the corresponding two cells of colD and colE) and then loop to the end of the left list.
Normally, I manually do this by put an IF comparing the cells in colA and colD, if different -> add a line a scroll down, then loop.

How can this be automate with a VBA Macro? I save you from my junk codes I tried so far, I think it's a super-easy question for you out there... :)

Thanks in advance
A.

Answer (score 0):

here is the idea:

define the cursor at the start of your column D.
Check if the value in your cursor cell is equal to the value in column A on the same row.
If not, add a cell in column D and  column E.
Then set your cursor to the cell below.
And redo until the list is finished.

```
    Sub test()
Dim cl As Range

Set cl = Range("D1")

Do While cl.Row < 10000
  If cl.Value <> cl.Offset(0, -3).Value Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    cl.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Set cl = cl.Offset(-1, 0)
  End If
  Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: sounds very good, but my VBA editor is stopping me saying that cl can't be declared as cell in the first line you mention

Comment: oups sorry, dim cl as range

Comment: now it's error runtime 424, point to the second line, the SET one

Comment: you have to replace yoursheet by the name of your sheet like Sheets("Sheet 1")